# How to check if Product is already in cart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webshop, where user can order products only 1 piece/product. I need to check if that user already has same product in cart and if is, alert that and not add that product to cart again. If product is not in cart, add it to cart.
This is first what I tried, but it always adds product to cart even terms in If is true. Problem is cart.

```
$(".glyphicon-shopping-cart").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#29d646");
    var BookID = $(this).parent().parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/selections/' + BookID,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
        },
        success: function(sel) {
            //check if Book is in cart already
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/api/carts',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(cart) {
                    if (cart.CompanyID == JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')) && cart.ISBN == sel.ISBN) {
                        alert('Product is already in cart');
                    } else {
                        var toCart = {
                            CompanyID: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')),
                            Orderdate: getdate(),
                            ISBN: sel.ISBN,
                            BookName: sel.BookName,
                            Author: sel.Author,
                            Publisher: sel.Publisher,
                            Price: sel.Price,
                            Season: sel.Season,
                            IsInCart: true,
                        };
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: '/api/Carts',
                            data: toCart,
                            success: function() {
                                console.log('Added to cart ' + BookID);
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                alert('Virhe!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This in another way I tried to do this, now IF -statement is working but still product is added to cart. What should I do?

```
//check if Book is in cart already
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/carts',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(cart) {
        $.each(cart, function(i, carts) {
            if (carts.CompanyID == JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')) && carts.ISBN == sel.ISBN) {
                alert('Product is already in cart');
            }
        })
        var toCart = {
            CompanyID: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')),
            Orderdate: getdate(),
            ISBN: sel.ISBN,
            BookName: sel.BookName,
            Author: sel.Author,
            Publisher: sel.Publisher,
            Price: sel.Price,
            Season: sel.Season,
            IsInCart: true,
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/api/Carts',
            data: toCart,
            success: function() {
                console.log('Added to cart ' + BookID);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Virhe!');
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

I don't know if this is right approach to this, if someone has better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var present=false;
$.each(cart, function(i, carts) {
if (carts.CompanyID == JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')) && 
carts.ISBN == sel.ISBN) {
alert('Product is already in cart');
present=true;
}
})
if(present===false){
other ajax part
}
```

Comment: Return is not working, still adding product to cart. Should that part, where product is added to cart be somewhere else in code?

Comment: your alert() is working ? i mean Product is already poping up or not?

Comment: Yes, alert is working, but still adds product to cart even it is there already

Comment: have you tried putting it in else section in second approach

Comment: No errors in console. What do you mean by second approach? Else can't be inside loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203998/discussion-between-deepak-and-heijoe).

Answer (score 0):

You can get out of the function immediately by adding `return`. It 'early exits' the function and will prevent the program to proceed in adding cart.

```
if (...) {
  alert('Product is already in cart');
  return;
}
```